# How do you check if user typed the specific word inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you check if user typed the specific text inside the textarea tag? Here is an example

```
 </head>
 <body>
            
            <textarea>
                            
            </textarea>
            <div class="box">
                            
            </div>
            <script>
                            (this is just example)
                            
                            if = user typed inside textarea this =("display (hi)")
                            do = build element inside .box the user typed inside the () of the text "display" 
            </script>
```

I really don't know how to do it i try to search it but none appeared and if you're confused with code it just glitched

Comment: Look at [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) first and see how to watch for changes on that element. You can then update the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the box element

Comment: Hmmm let me try that :)

Comment: Write some code and if you are still having problems come back and we'll help debug it.

Comment: Thank you :) but im new to js how do you add eventlistener with textcontent?

Comment: check [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) to learn javascript.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The event listener is attached to the text area. When the `change` event is fired a function is called. In that function you would check the `value` of the text area to see if it [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the search word, and then update the textContent of the box element which you probably selected with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). You may be new at this but it's also important for you to figure things out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope it will give you idea.
If use type any text and includes hi in textarea. It's will show all text in box container.

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.target.value.includes("hi")){
    box.innerHTML = "";
    box.append(`${e.target.value}`);
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: It actually doesn't work jnothing is showing in the div sorry

Comment: Text must include "hi" then It will show in Dev.
[JsBin -Example](https://jsbin.com/nixibuyuzu/edit?html,output)

Comment: What about it builds an element inside a div?

Comment: just replace this line.
document.querySelector('.box').innerHTML = `<h1>${e.target.value}</h1>`

Comment: snippet throws error

Comment: @DavePritlove You first have textarea and div with class box in DOM. Then you can use that [Example](https://jsbin.com/rojekogile/edit?html,output)

Comment: @DavePritlove you can now check snippet now. I added HTML elements.

Comment: @Obaidullah Ishfaq
 it works now you fixed it. It's a live snippet, don't post them unless you have checked they demonstrate what it intends.

Answer (score 0):

With the JS string function `includes`you can archive this.

```js
let block = false;
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

  function check(e) {
    const match = e.value.includes("hi");
    if (match && block === false) {
    box.innerHTML = 'Hello again'
    block = true;
  }  
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="check(this)"></textarea>
<div class="box"></div>
```